# Iterate nested ul with Thymeleaf

Tags: nested, iteration, thymeleaf

currently I have the following code to iterate an ArrayList and display it in a list in html:

```html
 <ul>
        <li th:each="section : ${sectionService.getAllSections()}">Section</li>
    </ul>
```

The output is something like this:

```html
 <ul>
    <li>Section1</li>
    <li>Section2</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Now i want to get something like this:

```html
 <ul>
    <li>Section1
        <ul>
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Section2</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

So is there any possibility to iterate over a list within an iteration?

Comment: Why not? If `section` inside the loop have `Collection` type or `section` have field with `Collection` type you can iterate it too .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just nest it.  For example (untested):

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="section : ${sectionService.getAllSections()}">
        <ul>
            <li th:each="anItem : ${section.subList}"></li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

where `subList` is the name of the `Collection` property within a `section`.